# Efficient upsampling of multidimensional array

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, expression-manipulation

I would like to efficiently upsample a multidimensional array.

It's a 5000*5 matrix where each element is a submatrix 12*12 and it
is that 12*12 matrix I want upsampled (to 24*24). The upsampling should
just replicate the value.

I have some code to illustrate:

```
arr = Table[Random[], {5000}, {5}, {12}, {12}];

ans = Map[ArrayFlatten,
    Map[{{#, #}, {#, #}} &, arr, {4}], {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.6501516, Null} *)

ans // Dimensions

(* {5000, 5, 24, 24} *)

ans[[3, 4, 1 ;; 5, 1 ;; 5]] // MatrixForm
```

Is there a faster way? I am using Mathematica version 8, but could be
persuaded to upgrade if a new version makes this much faster.

I am also thinking of going down the GPU route at some point, so anything
that was suitable for GPU would also be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked into using `Riffle[]` if it's just a simple duplication you want?

Comment: Alternatively, Mathematica 10 did introduce `ArrayResample[]` - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html, although it actually seems slow...

Comment: The Riffle documentation suggests it just Riffle's lists rather than arrays.

Comment: I have seen the ArrayResample documentation for Mathematica 10, it looked from the documentation as if it padded the array by inserting zero's whereas I am looking for padded with the neighbouring value.

Comment: @Julian, right, so you do a double riffle; riffle up each row, and then riffle the matrix to duplicate rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using method that Guess who it is suggested I managed to get around 75% faster result.

```
Unsample[x_] := Nest[Riffle[#, #]\[Transpose] &, x, 2]

ans = Map[Unsample, arr, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Your suggested solution evaluates in 1 to 1.2 sec on my machine, while this one evaluates in 0.63 s. I suspect that this method can be further improved.

*Note by Mr.Wizard: code mildly refactored.*

Comment: Well, it was intended as a starting suggestion after all… :D

Comment: Julian, consider marking question "answered" if you (indeed) find it to be answered sufficiently :)

Comment: I have used Neven's code fragment. I think it's missing a Transpose in Unsample (at end), and replacing Table with the Map at level {2} I've got us down to .55 secs which is about 5X faster, so thanks guys!

Comment: Ok, added Transpose which I missed first time. Sorry for that

Comment: Great. Nevan, How do I mark it as answered? (Can't see anything on user interface?)

Comment: To be honest, I never post questions so I have no idea :). But I see for instance this link. Maybe things are a bit different on mathematica page. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done. Thanks for the link, and would upvote you if I had sufficient reputation points. But have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr=RandomReal[1,{5000,5,12,12}];

r1=Map[ArrayFlatten,Map[{{#,#},{#,#}}&,arr,{4}],{2}];//AbsoluteTiming
r2=Flatten[Map[{{#,#},{#,#}}&,arr,{4}],{{1},{2},{3,5},{4,6}}];//AbsoluteTiming
r3=Map[With[{t=Transpose@Riffle[#,#]},Transpose@Riffle[t,t]]&,arr,{2}];//AbsoluteTiming

cf = With[{code = 
     ArrayFlatten@
      Map[{{#, #}, {#, #}} &, 
       Array[Quiet @ \[FormalA][[##]] &, {12, 12}], {2}]}, 
   Compile[{{\[FormalA], _Real, 2}}, code, RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]];

r4=cf[arr];//AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: chyaong, I made a couple of changes to your code; I hope you do not mind.  If you do please just revert the edit.

Comment: I would appreciate your adding my method to your benchmark.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No problem.

Answer (score 2):

I propose using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) itself to complete this transformation.  In miniature:

```
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};

m[[{1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2}]] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & a & b & b \\
 a & a & b & b \\
 c & c & d & d \\
 c & c & d & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

A function specific to your tensor dimensions:

```
fn1[m_] := m[[All, All, #, #]] & @ ⌈Range[24]/2⌉
```

This is about four times faster than the presently Accepted answer and competitive with chyaong's compiled function.

```
arr = RandomReal[1, {5000, 5, 12, 12}];

fn1[arr] // Dimensions // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0324, {5000, 5, 24, 24}}
> ```

### Generalization

This function may be generalized as follows:

```
upsample[a_?TensorQ, lev_] := a[[##]] & @@
  Replace[_Integer :> All] /@
    MapAt[⌈Range[2 #]/2⌉ &, Dimensions[a], List /@ lev]
```

Applied to your case:

```
upsample[arr, {3, 4}] // Dimensions // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.032, {5000, 5, 24, 24}}
> ```

But also:

```
t = ArrayReshape[Alphabet[], {2, 2, 2, 2}];

upsample[t, 1] // MatrixForm

upsample[t, 3] // MatrixForm

upsample[t, {2, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]